# i want read a source file and write data into .Csv file in Spark scala with additional identity columns

Tags: scale, azure-hdinsight

i want to read a CSV file and store into a csv file with few additional columns like auto-generated columns identity columns, load date time.

I am using spark 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use withColumn method to add columns to DataFrame.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@withColumn(colName:String,col:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame